# Conditional statement inside animate/any function

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-animate

I was wondering whether it is possible to set a property inside jQuery's `animate` based on some criteria. Example:

```
var condition = offL > ((wW / 2) - $this.width());
tooltip.css(function() {
  if (condition) {
    return '"right", "auto"';
  } else {
    return '"left", "auto"';
  }
}).animate({
  "top": $this.offset().top + (posT / 2) - (tooltip.height() / 2),
  if (condition) {
    return '"left":"offL - tooltip.width() - 30"';
  } else {
    return '"right", "offR - tooltip.width() - 30"';
  }
}, 300).fadeTo(200, 1);
```

(`tooltip` and other vars are defined earlier.)

This does not work, obviously. But, how would one go about if they need to use conditional arguments inside functions?

Another side question, is my usage of my condition as a `var` correct?

Comment: You don't, you build out a variable to hold the data you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply made the decision before the animation.
for exampaple:

```
var properties = {}
if(condtion) {
  properties = {left: someThing};
else
  properties = {prop1: value1, prop2: value2};
$(obj).animate(properties,'fast');
```

and yes, your usage of condition is correct.

```
var condition = offL > ((wW / 2) - $this.width());
```

will be evaluated to true or false since its a condition ;)